# IIS 7.5 url rewritter 2.0 Help creating a rule

Tags: iis-7.5, rewrite

I am looking to rewrite an url.  Say I have an URL like `www.domain.com/wall.aspx?Personid=1` and I want to rewrite that as `www.domain.com/wall/personid/1` or even `www.domain.com/wall/1`. I am wanting it to do that same thing for all the urls on my page.

Is there a way to get everything before `.aspx`, then remove `.aspx?` and add `/` and remove `=` and add `/`?

How could I do this using IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

The shorter version is nicer and cleaner I think. The following rewrite rule should do what you want:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Wall URL's" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^wall/(.+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/wall.aspx?Personid={UrlEncode:{R:1}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```